# How to utilize Android Car API inside an app

Tags: android, android-auto

I want to test and (if possible) utilize Android Car API functionalities inside my Android app. Specifically, I need to be able to import classes under `android.car.*` package which can be seen here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/packages.html

I also found the repo on Google Git: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/

How should I add this library as a dependency in my app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The library is now released as part of Android Q SDK in Android Studio. You need to

1. update the SDK 29 to minor version 5 using SDK manager
2. Update app module build.gradle include car-lib

   ```
   android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
        ...
        useLibrary 'android.car'
   }
   ```
3. API documentation is available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/Car)

Comment: Where this lib came from:

useLibrary 'android.car'

if you compile standalone project, not a part of AOSP.

Comment: see #1, use SDK Manager in Android Studio.

Comment: Doesn't work. Package android.car.Car still unavailable. Google as always cant provide normal guide.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me so here is how I achieved it  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75424665/4875245

Answer (score 5):

**Edit: This answer is outdated. Use the method in the accepted answer now that the tooling has been updated and the lib is part of the platform.**

There's no prebuilt binary for `android.car`, but you can build it yourself by running `mm` in `packages/services/Car/car-lib`:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/refs/heads/master/car-lib/Android.bp#50

If your app has an `.mk` or `.bp` file, you can include the library like `CarService` does here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/service/Android.mk#42

The library is mostly meant for OEMs though and not so much for third parties.

Comment: Also found this in Google's issue tracker for some supporting info: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74386715

Comment: `make android.car`does not work. how can I create android.car.jar from Android.bp?

Comment: Sorry, I'll update the answer. If you run mm in packages/services/Car/car-lib it should install the android.car.jar into target/product/<product_name>/system/framework/android.car.jar.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I run `mm` or `mma` command: `Couldn't locate the top of the tree.  Try setting TOP.`

Comment: TOP or ANDROID_BUILD_TOP should be the root of the AOSP tree. I thought "source build/envsetup" would set that up though.

Answer (score 1):

**This is how I achieved Car APIs (android.car.Car) for My Application**

```
Note: You need to have AOSP code to achieve this solution
```

Step1.
Go to your AOSP code base and run below mentioned commands

```
AOSP$ source build/envsetup.sh

AOSP$ lunch aosp_car_x86-userdebug

AOSP$ cd packages/services/Car/car-lib
AOSP$ mm
```

Once car-lib module is built successfully, Go to below mentioned path and copy **classes.jar file**

```
AOSP$ cd out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.car_intermediates/
```

Copy that **classes.jar** file and paste in your projects **libs folder** (e.g. MyApp/app/libs)

right click on the classes.jar file in libs and select **Add as Library** option

**OR**

you can directly add `implementation files('libs/classes.jar')` in your dependencies in build.gradle (app) file

Hope this answer will help

Answer (score 0):

For Linux you need to first set the environment and then build it:

```
. build/envsetup.sh

lunch aosp_car_x86-userdebug

make -j8
```

Answer (score 0):

For those where https://stackoverflow.com/a/63321234/361413 doesn't work due to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234749386: here's how to incorporate the android.car.jar without the use of AOSP (it's in the SDK, but not found by Android Studio...):

1. Locate the android.car.jar that corresponds to your app's `compileSdk` value. For instance for `compileSdk=33`, the jar can be found in `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platforms/android-33/optional/android.car.jar`
2. Copy it to the `app/libs/` directory in your app's source root.
3. In your `app/build.gradle`, add the following stanza to `dependencies`: `implementation files('libs/android.car.jar')`