# Android Studio Car API

Tags: android, android-source, automotive, android-automotive

Im trying to add android.car API to Android Studio project. Since car classes are not available by default with sdk, i've done mm in .../car-lib and copied generated android.car.jar to app/libs and then right click on this in AS and -> Add as a library. After this Car Api classes are still not available. To make everything clear, here are steps I done:

```
/AOSP$ . build/envsetup.sh
/AOSP$ lunch full-eng
/AOSP$ cd packages/services/Car/car-lib
/AOSP/packages/services/Car/car-lib$ mm
```

Then copied android.car.jar from AOSP/out/target/product/generic/system/framework/android.car.jar to MyProject/app/libs.
Then in Android Studio right click on android.car.jar and -> Add as a library (auto generate grandle implementation)

Comment: Car SDK is now released for Android Q. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, already got it.

Project Structure → + Module → import .Jar/AAR Package → 
Source:

`AOSP/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.car_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar`

Then same with

```
AOSP/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.car_intermediates/classes.jar
```

Then add those modules as a module dependencies to your app module.

Comment: I was trying to build it from AOSP but couldnt because i have a case insensitive filesystem and it failed =( . I was wondering if you have that .jar still somewhere so you could share it? would save me a lot of hussle