# Is Android Automotives Car API only meant for OEMs?

Tags: android-automotive

The AOSP Automotive documentation states that third party apps should use the ***Car API***`("VehicleNetworkService. Controls vehicle HAL with built-in security. Access restricted to system components only (non-system components such as third party apps should use car API instead)"`,`https://source.android.com/devices/automotive`).

That is quite confusing because the android developer documentations state, that the only supported type of app is a media app which does not even draw its own UI except sign in and settings(https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/automotive-os).

So is there a possibility to write other apps than media ones that may even use the car api to read the vehicle speed for example?

Answer (score 1):

Car SDK is now released to developers and many Car APIs can be reached by third party apps, however privileged apps i.e. apps that are part of android system image and designed as privileged, can access more functionality that 3rd party apps. The access is gated by Android permissions.

See [How to utilize Android Car API inside an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125921) for my answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than cross linking questions the better option is to check to see if one of the questions is a duplicate of the other and flag the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can develop any app running in Android Automotive Enviroment (i dont want to called it Android Automotive OS because it simply Android )
Google only given some advice/rules how to design your app in the way it good for Automotive product. Login, Car status check , Driver distraction limit...vv.

For 3rd developer sure you have to use Car API what car OEM offer and might require OEM's SDK also..
Goolge as of now only provide some kind of permisison that you can add to your app manifest. Then hopefully it can get correct information if OEM supported in thier IVI.
adb shell pm list permissions | grep car